# which aws serverless to host aspnet core website?

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

We have a aspnet core web application and want to deploy to AWS serverless. 
Do AWS Lambda allows aspnet core website to be hosted? 
I know lambda supports running "serverless.AspNetCoreWebApp" application, but my application is created using visual studio 2017 with ".net core 2.1". What changes are needed to deploy this website to lambda?

Comment: Try to refer to this article:https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/developer/deploy-an-existing-asp-net-core-web-api-to-aws-lambda/

Comment: Above link seems to answer web api with lambda, which is good. Does that mean, aws lambda can be used to run aspnet mvc razor views?

Comment: I am not sure, you could ask on its [github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/149).But it supports Razor Pages.https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/developer/serverless-asp-net-core-2-0-applications/

Comment: Hi, have you figured out creating serverless app with razor pages using aws lambda